# TSQL FOR JSON OUTER APPLY returns empty object

Tags: json, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL script.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (T1Col1 INT, T1Col2 INT)
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (T2Col1 INT, T2Col2 INT)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,11),(2,22)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (1,100),(1,101)

SELECT * 
FROM  
    @T1 A 
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT T2Col2 
     FROM @T2 B 
     WHERE B.T2Col1 = A.T1Col1) AB 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

which returns the following json.

```
[{
    "T1Col1": 1,
    "T1Col2": 11,
    "AB": [{
        "T2Col2": 100
    }, {
        "T2Col2": 101
    }]
}, {
    "T1Col1": 2,
    "T1Col2": 22,
    "AB": [{}]
}]
```

My question is how to avoid empty object inside the array, ie `[]` instead of `[{}]`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can get empty array, but you can get `null` value instead `[{}]`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    @T1 A 
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT T2Col2 
     FROM @T2 B 
     WHERE B.T2Col1 = A.T1Col1 FOR JSON PATH) AB (T2Col2)
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

[image]

You can check easily if the element is `null` instead of checking for empty array, I guess.

Comment: Could it help using JSON_MODIFY with lax mode?